# SHIFT+SPACE on terminal sends escape sequence

Tags: escape-characters, iterm2

am using iTerm with Tmux, but I see this without tmux. If I hit `SHIFT+SPACE` I get the escape sequence `^[[32;2u`. Is there a way to suppress it or disable that escape sequence? I am not seeing it in my preferences as a predefined escape sequence

Comment: The solution depends on the application that enables the xterm [modifyOtherKeys](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:modifyOtherKeys) feature.  iTerm2 recently adapted/imitated/whatever this from xterm.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey, there ended up being a setting in iTerm called: `Report modifiers using CSI u`, disabling that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution depends on the application that enables the xterm [**`modifyOtherKeys`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:modifyOtherKeys) feature. iTerm2 recently adapted/imitated/whatever this from xterm.

The xterm manual in turn mentions a page in the FAQ [*XTerm – “Other” Modified Keys*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/modified-keys.html) which gives information on the feature, and in that page's [*Other Programs*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/modified-keys.html#otherprogs) section points to an [*iTerm2 discussion*](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/iterm2-discuss/KpSlgnY_zxw/UWrOdPZpDAAJ) where Nachman added the CSI u feature in January 2019.  That gives the same information as **`modifyOtherKeys`**, using a slightly different format (see [**`formatOtherKeys`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:formatOtherKeys), which dates from [2008](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_235)).

Here's a screenshot showing the preference:

[image: preference dialog from iTerm2]

The "?" help points to [iTerm2's website](https://iterm2.com/documentation-csiu.html), which is a bit lacking in depth ([ymmv](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ymmv)).  My intention when I developed the feature was that *applications* would enable it temporarily, rather than making the *terminal* turn it on indefinitely.