# In vim: stop SHIFT+SPACE from discarding all unsaved changes

Tags: ssh, vim, iterm2

Every time I type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in `vim`, it undoes all changes to the file that have not yet been written. I would like this to not happen, as it is extremely easy to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by accident.

I am using iTerm2, and am ssh'ed into a remote machine. When I use vim (in iTerm2) on my local (OSX) machine, this issue does not occur. When I use the default terminal instead of iTerm2, this does not occur, even when ssh'ed into the same system. So: only the combination of iTerm2 + being in an ssh session seems to cause problems.

I have never modified any vim keybindings; I have no `~/.vimrc`, and `:verbose Map <S-Space>` doesn't show any binding. This makes me think this is an iTerm2 issue - but I don't understand why it would not cause this problem when running a shell on my local machine. Are there any iTerm2 profile settings that apply only in ssh? Or should I look elsewhere for this issue?

Comment: It's not clear from your question:  if you are **not** running in tmux or iTerm2, does the Shift-Space keystroke still wipe your changes?

Comment: On macOS, in Vim within `tmux`, running in iTerm2, I can not reproduce this behaviour.  Nothing binds `Shift`+`Space` out of these applications, nor does the macOS GUI as far as I can tell.

Comment: have you check `~/.vimrc` for some previous :map?

Comment: Even without tmux, this happens. However, it only appears to happen in vim when I am running on another system I have ssh'ed to - it does not happen in vim on my local machine. I have no ~/.vimrc file, so unless there is somewhere mappings can be stored, I'm not sure. Fortunately, I was wrong about the changes being discarded - they can be redone, I just have to hit ^r several times (I guess the undo buffer, if that's the right term, gets some empty changes in it that I have to redo past in order to actually redo my edits.)

Comment: Do you have a custom Vim setup on the remote machine? You say "I have no `~/.vimrc`" but it's unclear what system your are referring to (the local or the remote).

Comment: Unfortunately no, no ~/.vimrc on the remote nor on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - the problem was the iTerm2 setting "Report modifiers using CSI u", as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625016/shiftspace-on-terminal-sends-escape-sequence). Disabling that fixed the issue.

I thought this might be the problem and disabled it before, but it seems that it only takes effect on restarting iTerm2 (or perhaps closing the session), so I mistakenly excluded that as the culprit.